# Modifying relevance score in elasticsearch using results from another query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine

A project I am working on utilizes elasticsearch as a search engine. I also am using a graph database to keep track of user actions and the relationships between queries, clicks, etc.

What I want to do is index queries and their top results from the graph database into elasticsearch, so at query time, I can boost the elasticsearch _score by the score provided by the graph database. Is this possible in elasticsearch itself? Or do I need to do the boosting externally?

Comment: Do you intend to store in ES in some kind of temporary index the results of you graph DB query? Or all the documents are always in an ES index?

Comment: @macebalp I am thinking of storing the alternate rankings in another index say `alt_rankings`, which I query for the document containing the top ranked documents given a search term. At the same time, I would like to query the other primary indices for ES' top ranked documents. I would then like to combine ES' score with that found in the `alt_rankings` index for that given query, document pair.

Comment: @LukeLaFountaine Any success with this?

Answer (score 2):

If i understad your problem, you have your primary results comming from another source (graph DB) and that score is highly dependent of every query as it is with Elasticsearch. [Script score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) functions in ES are not suited for this task, as you have limited parameters to pass to it besides accessing all indexed document's fields. So the only choices I can see are:

1. Index the primary results including the external score and then perform a query using the above mentioned script score or simpler [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions). Note that besides obvious efficiency drawbacks(indexing load on ES, roundtrips, etc), this index will contain only a subset of documents and it will highly affect the relevancy of the terms.
2. Filter an ES index and combine the result externally calculating whichever new score fits you. I would advice this one, note that if you want to get only documents found by first query you should try to **filter** by their ids like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) or like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) depending on your version, so the ES score is only made up of the terms you wanted to look for and their relevance.

Answer (score 0):

> boost the elasticsearch _score by the score

You can boost the score of the documents during elasticsearch query using the [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Comment: How would I be able to query for the alternate score within the function score query? That seems to only work for fixed functions or for functions of fields that are on the document that is to be boosted.

Comment: Have a look at the [field value factor function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor). You can combine the es score with a value of a field.

Comment: I am aware of the function score query stuff, but not sure if that will be able to accommodate this need. From what I see, the field that you are boosting by needs to be part of the same document that is being boosted. Is there a way to boost it based on the field of a document from another query?